# SpriteKit: how to make SKEmitterNode particles twinkle?

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skemitternode

The SKEmitterNode in SpriteKit lets you change particle properties, but how can you animate the particles so they twinkle like at the 0:12 mark of this video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYy2G0lVTAM

Is this possible?

We tried rapidly alternating the color from yellow to white (the sprite is white originally) but this doesn't achieve the desired twinkling effect:

```
        let colorizeYellow = SKAction.colorize(with: UIColor.yellow, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.2)
        let colorizeReset = SKAction.colorize(withColorBlendFactor: 0.0, duration: 0.2)
        let colorizeSequence = SKAction.sequence([colorizeYellow, colorizeReset])
        let colorizeRepeat = SKAction.repeatForever(colorizeSequence)
```

Comment: If you just want to change colors then that is what the color ramp is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation, you can add actions to particles:

> This means you can perform other interesting tricks, such as
>   animating the particle’s textures.

In the video example you provided, most particles start at full "twinkle" and get smaller over time, until just a dot is left that quickly fades away. So start with a twinkle sprite (kind of like a plus sign with faded tips), scale it down and crossfade it with a plain dot that also fades out as it scales down. That should be very close to the effect in the video.